# Is it possible to force CMake to run add_compile_definitions() each time?

Tags: cmake, esp-idf

I have an embedded project (using ESP-IDF which builds projects with CMake), where I have a props.json file that contains several settings (e.g. "device type"). For example based on the actual value of `"deviceType"` the CMake open and read props.json by calling `execute_process()` and `jq`, then defines C preprocessor macros, such as: `DEVICE_TYPE_A` by using `add_compile_definitions()`.

The problem is that, this will run only when I modify the CMakeLists.txt or clean the whole project, but I don't want to recompile each components when I change the props.json only the files that I wrote (so, depend on the settings). I'd like to make CMake read the file each time I build the project without cleaning it.

I did my research, so I know there are `add_custom_target()` and `add_custom_command()` that behave that way, however `add_compile_definitions()` cannot be called in a script. Is there a solution to achieve this or should I just use a header file configured by `configure_file()` and leave `add_compile_definitions()` alone?

Comment: soo just reconfigure cmake, it will detect changes automatically. `only the files that I wrote` then do `target_compile_definitions` and add the compile definitions only to these target that depend on that macro. It looks very similar to what zephyr is already doing - don't you want to use it, instead of writing your own code?

Comment: @KamilCuk Wow, I feel so stupid, right now. I tried to reconfigure before, but it built the whole project (of course, since I use the root CMakeLists.txt...). I've tried what you suggested: it works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: @prodx - you should never need to manually reconfigure CMake if your build is correct!! Use the `CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS` property, as I show in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy and you *don't* need to manually reconfigure CMake. Just add the following to the `CMakeLists.txt` in the directory containing your `props.json` file:

```
set_property(DIRECTORY . APPEND PROPERTY CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS props.json)
```

This will add `props.json` to the list of files that the CMake-generated build scans when determining whether to re-run the CMake configure step. See the docs on [`CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS.html) for more detail.

---

In general, you should *never* need to manually re-run CMake<sup>1</sup> after the first configure. If you do, it is an indication that you have not communicated all of the necessary information for CMake to generate a correct build system.

<sup>1</sup> There is one notable exception: Xcode is known to be buggy when re-running the CMake configure step automatically.